# Structure of the magento product tables

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Does anyone know how the structure of products in magento is created? When creating a product which is the first table to receive values ​​and its following .. I need to export my data to another magento, when I do a dump and step to a new bank the products are in the backend and everything else, the preview in the frontend also, but when I click on the product returns me 404, I opened the product in the backend and missing some product tabs, I came to the conclusion that in magento there are several foreign keys, so it depends on one table to be able to add another, would anyone have the order of these tables or do you have any source of which tables I have to insert? 
**Example:** `catalog_product_entity after catalog_product_url_key after ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a real foreign key constraint, then mysql should inform you about it during importing the dump. As most keys are either attribute related or entity_id i would assume that those tables have to come first (catalog_product_entity, eav_attribute, eav_attribute_option, eav_attribute_option_values come to my mind directly)

could it be a problem of non running indexing ? Missing tabs sound more like missing extensions than missing product data, as the data normally only supplies the data for the adminhtml forms.